# Django - Invalid block tag: 'csrf_tokan', expected 'endblock'

Tags: django

I cannot understand why my django app does not understand template tags.
I get this error:

Invalid block tag: 'csrf_tokan', expected 'endblock'

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^index/', 'myproj.views.index'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

views.py:

```
@staff_member_required
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', locals())
```

index.html:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
     {% csrf_tokan %}
{% endblock %}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe just due to a typo but I did the same thing today (crsf_token) so happy to run across this example.

Comment: Happened to stumble upon this post, In my case it was `csfr_token` instead of `csrf_token`!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
     {% csrf_token %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: ops, I could not see that :)

Comment: No worries, it happens to everyone at some point.